# why is this not working echo in php?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, echo

okay so im trying to enter a dynamic meta tag for the facebook api and some wierd things are happnening.

here is how im getting the value

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$id = intval($id);
```

and this is where i input it.

```
 <meta property="og:url" content="http://blaze-craft.com/matt/gag.php?id=<?php echo $id ?       >" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://blaze-craft.com/matt/get.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" />
```

But it is always outputing the value as 0 even when its not 0. Also when i echo it out anywhere else on the page it works?

any help would be great thanks! :D

Okay iv just seen in the source code it is being set

```
<html>
<head>
<title>YourGag - Gag</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="MyGag - Gag" />
<meta property="og:type" content="activity" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://blaze-craft.com/matt/gag.php?id=2" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://blaze-craft.com/matt/get.php?id=2" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YourGag" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1254694731" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
```

but when im use the facebook debugger its saying that there is a 0 there instead of a 2!

seriosly wierd!

Comment: `var_dump ($_GET['id']);` should give you the value of id for debugging

Comment: Fix your whitespace - we can only assume that is a typo `?     >`

Comment: Is your page responding to a `POST` request?  If so, the `$_GET` variables won't be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried debugging the value of `$_GET['id']` before attempting to cast as an `int`?

Per the documention ([`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)):

> **Return Values**
>
> The integer value of `var` on success, or `0` on failure. Empty arrays
>   return `0`, non-empty arrays return `1`.

So `$_GET['id']` is either an empty array or cannot be returned as an integer value.

Comment: var_dump($_GET['id']);

This returns  string[1]"2"

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1. did you try seeing if the `$_GET['id']` variable is set?
2. you should escape the ID being sent in the meta tag. E.g. `echo urlencode($id);`
3. if that fails, make a very simple page that like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  echo "id is set: '".$_GET['id']."'";
}
else {
  echo "id is not set";
}
```

just to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of $id before you cast it with intval()? The return value of 0 from intval is telling you that $id is not a valid scalar value to pass to the function. It is either an object, an array or some other value that is causing it to fail.

As an alternative you might try:

```
$id = (int)$id;
```